# Jquery dropdown with image doesn't show

Tags: jquery

I am using the http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/blog/jquery-image-dropdown and it have no problem showing the dropdown but when I included the dropdown to a hidden div (which will add back later) the dropdown doesn't work properly.

when you can click on "Please choose color" it have no problem showing, but when you "add more image" and click on another "Please choose color", the dropdown can't drop down.

Please let me know what have I done wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="dd.css" />
 <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery.dd.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".colormenu").msDropDown();

 var spotMax = 4;
 if($('.spot').size() >= spotMax) { $(obj).hide(); }

 $("#add").click(function(){ addSpot(this, spotMax); });
});

function addSpot(obj, sm) {
    var num = eval($('.spot').size()) + 1;
    var upload_area = $('#upload_area').html();

    $('#spots').append('<div class="spot">'+upload_area+'</div>').find(".remove").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
        $('#add').show();
    });

    if($('.spot').size() >= sm) {
        $(obj).hide();
    }
}
</script>    
</head>
<body>

<div id="spots">
 <div>
  <input type="file" name="pic[]" />
  <select name="color_id[]" class="colormenu" width="150" style="width:150px"  >
  <option value="0">Please choose color</option>
   <option value="14" data-image="/img/color-code/14.jpg">Gold</option>
   <option value="15" data-image="/img/color-code/15.jpg">Beige</option>
   <option value="138" data-image="/img/color-code/138.jpg">Rose Gold</option>
  </select>
 </div> 


 <div id="upload_area" style="display:none;">
  <div style="height:8px;">&nbsp;</div>

  <input type="file" name="pic[]" />
  <select name="color_id[]" class="colormenu" width="150" style="width:150px">
  <option value="0">Please choose color</option>
   <option value="14" data-image="/img/color-code/14.jpg">Gold</option>
   <option value="15" data-image="/img/color-code/15.jpg">Beige</option>
  </select> <a style="cursor:pointer;" class="remove">Remove this image</a>

 </div>

 <input type="button" name="add" id="add" value="Add more Image" />
</div>
```

Comment: Is that the actual page you're loading? Can you create a jsFiddle for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add the `msdropdown` only on visible elements; then when you show items attach the plugin again.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".colormenu:visible").msDropDown();

    var spotMax = 4;
    if ($('.spot').size() >= spotMax) {
        $(obj).hide();
    }

    $("#add").click(function () {
        addSpot(this, spotMax);
    });
});

function addSpot(obj, sm) {
    var num = eval($('.spot').size()) + 1;
    var upload_area = $('#upload_area').html();

    $('#spots').append('<div class="spot">' + upload_area + '</div>').find(".remove").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
        $('#add').show();
    });

    if ($('.spot').size() >= sm) {
        $(obj).hide();
    }

     $(".colormenu:visible").msDropDown();
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lz3aW/